# Change add to cart to sold out

Tags: opencart

I have made a script to change "add to cart" to "sold out", but I'm not sure what I have done wrong.
In my opencart 2.0.3.1 I can't seem to get it working, but it works great in opencart 1.5.x

Since the xml file is too big to post it here, I linked it here http://nicotineeliquids.com.au/matt/SHOW_SOLD_OUT_IF_PRODUCT_QUANTITY_IS_ZERO.xml

I'm not sure what I need to change, please help me to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: how can i add the xml file here

Comment: how do i improve the formatting im new here

Comment: http://www.nicotineeliquids.com.au/download  you can get the file here

Comment: Click the "Edit" link below your questin and change the link you originally provided to the one that works, please.